# MongoDB update where multiple condition match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have the below mongoDB document:

```
        {
        "_id" : "5b76c3c037548390fdb5b40e",
        "userId" : "4601",
        "news" : [
            {
                "newsId" : "1",
                "progress" : "0",
            },
            {
                "newsId" : "2",
                "progress" : "100",
            },
            {
                "newsId" : "3",
                "progress" : "45",
            },
        ],
        "modified" : ISODate("2018-08-21T19:13:43.301+05:30"),
        "created" : ISODate("2018-08-21T19:13:43.301+05:30"),
        "completionStatus" : "0",
    },
    {
        "_id" : "5b76c3c037548390fdb5b40e",
        "userId" : "1234",
        "news" : [
            {
                "newsId" : "2",
                "progress" : "100",
            },
            {
                "newsId" : "3",
                "progress" : "100",
            },
        ],
        "modified" : ISODate("2018-08-21T19:13:43.301+05:30"),
        "created" : ISODate("2018-08-21T19:13:43.301+05:30"),
        "completionStatus" : "0",
    }
```

news array can contain n number of JSONs. for one user count of this array is 3 for other it is 2.

Now I want to update **completionStatus** to 1 based on the below conditions:

Condition 1 : **modified** date of document is today. there is already a **modified** key.

Condition 2 : **progress** of every elements of the news array is 100.

Answer (score 1):

This should works:

```
collection.update({
  modified: {
    $gte: startOfDay,
    $lte: endOfDay
  },
  news: {
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {
        progress: {
          $ne: "100"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  $set: {
    completionStatus: "1"
  }
});
```